# How to search . in XPath in SonarQube

Tags: xpath, sonarqube

My requirement is to search "using System.Resources;" in SonarQube. I can use the following XPath to search the keyword "Resources".

```
//*[@tokenValue='Resources']
```

But if I change to this pattern, it doesn't work. I think the reason is the dot, but I have no idea how to search it in XPath. Is there an escape character for it? I use "\", but not work.

```
//*[@tokenValue='System.Resources']
```

Update: I think the reason is 'System.Resources' are separated into 2 levels in XML. But still not know how to search the pattern by XPath.

```
  <NAMESPACE_NAME tokenValue="System" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="6">
    <NAMESPACE_OR_TYPE_NAME tokenValue="System" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="6">
      <IDENTIFIER tokenValue="System" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="6"/>
      <DOT tokenValue="." tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="12"/>
      <IDENTIFIER tokenValue="Resources" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="13"/>
    </NAMESPACE_OR_TYPE_NAME>
  </NAMESPACE_NAME>
```

Comment: well if you find an element based on an attribute equal to Resources, it can not at the same time be equal to System.Resources. The dot should not be an issue. How does your XML data look like?

Comment: You might also want to explain how you search using XQuery in SonarQube? I don't know this tool and just googled it and I have not discovered any way to search using XQuery.

Comment: I want to scan "System.Resources", "Resource" is just a test. I think I know the reason, "System.Resources" will be separated to 2 levels.
 You can reference this URL for SonarQube's customized rule. http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Extending+Coding+Rules

Comment: First of all, this is XPath and not XQuery. According to the webpage you linked to SonarQube only supports XPath 1.0, which is a small subset of XQuery (especially XQuery 3.0). The reason you can't find anything using `//*[@tokenValue='System.Resources']` is, because there simply is no element with the attribute `tokenValue` being `System.Resources`.

Comment: In your XML, which element would like to get? Could you please provide your _expected output_? It is unclear to me, do you want the `NAMESPACE_OR_TYPE_NAME` element or something else?

Answer (score 1):

The string `System.Resources` is spread across three different elements in your input XML. That is why an expression like

```
//*[@tokenValue='Resources']
```

can never find it, because there is no single `IDENTIFIER` element that has both "System" and "Resources" as attribute values. So, you have to look for something else. Why not a `NAMESPACE_OR_TYPE_NAME` element? Use for example:

```
//NAMESPACE_OR_TYPE_NAME[IDENTIFIER/@tokenValue = 'System' and IDENTIFIER/@tokenValue = 'Resources']
```

I am not sure whether there is any significance to the dot `.`in between "System" and "Resources", but this expression just ignores it.

---

To illustrate all this, there is an XSLT stylesheet below.

**XML Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NAMESPACE_NAME tokenValue="System" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="6">
    <NAMESPACE_OR_TYPE_NAME tokenValue="System" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="6">
      <IDENTIFIER tokenValue="System" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="6"/>
      <DOT tokenValue="." tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="12"/>
      <IDENTIFIER tokenValue="Resources" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="13"/>
    </NAMESPACE_OR_TYPE_NAME>
  </NAMESPACE_NAME>
```

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="NAMESPACE_OR_TYPE_NAME[IDENTIFIER/@tokenValue = 'System' and IDENTIFIER/@tokenValue = 'Resources']">
        <bingo/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Output**

```
<bingo/>
```